# send_data can't send large file - after 30 seconds, kills the request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, unicorn

I have a rails app on nginx/unicorn with this line of code:

```
    format.csv { send_data Test_Model.to_csv, stream: 'true', filename: "assets-#{DateTime.now.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')}.csv" }
```

The problem is - the file that is generated by my to_csv method is on the large side, 2.4 MB - **it also takes a long time for my app to produce it via sql queries**... and that longness is not something I can change.

So then, 90% of the time I invoke my functionality I get:

[image: what I always get]

Maybe 1 in 10 times, I do get the file to come out. But the point is... it would be of tremendous use to generate this and send it via send_data.

I know there is talk of send_file. However, send_file expects a filepath of an already-generated file. In this case, I want to dynamically create this data with send_data. I really want to push this file out of send_data if at all possible - even if it takes my app >30+ seconds to produce the file.

**UPDATE**

So my app sort of "times out" and bites the dust at 30 seconds. Sounds an awful lot like a timeout setting somewhere. I wonder - would send_data timeout be set in unicorn conf, or in generic rails conf? **How can I manipulate the timeout associated with send_data**?

Comment: I don't see any problem sending a bigger file (and 2.4 MB is not that big). What server do you use? Can you test it with `curl -I http://yourpath` and post the output? Generic Network Errors from a browser can mask the problem

Comment: How long does it take to generate the csv data?

Comment: @23tux It takes several seconds to generate. 15-30 seconds, roughly.

Comment: @23tux Ah - a quick check sees that my app times it out at exactly 30 seconds. This is a unicorn app... perhaps there is config related? Is that config webserver or Rails project related, I wonder? I will include that question in the main thread, as well as tag unicorn

Comment: Whats your environment / server setup?  Does it fail in development mode, or production mode?

Comment: @JohnNaegle It fails in both

Comment: Are you running on heroku?  Heroku has a router timeout of 30 seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ngnix will terminate connections that take too long.  Long connections mean your application potentially isn't able to serve other requests.  Besides re-writing your request to use ActiveJob, or some other background generation, you could check the nginx confirmation parameter [`keepalive_timeout`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#keepalive_timeout).

Comment: Yes this would be how to change it. We have some of our reporting servers set to 60 or even 90 seconds. Additionally this could be a browser concern itself. Usually with large files or files that take a while to process we make AJAX requests for this exact reason.

Comment: Hey @John Naegle I changed my keepalive_timeout setting in nginx.conf to 90 seconds as opposed to the default 5. However, I still get my request truncated at 30 seconds. Trying to find relevant unicorn config now - it is bizarre that it appears this timeout is being governed by something aside from that aptly-named nginx setting.

Comment: @PinkElephantsOnParade browsers will timeout for you if they believe the connection. As I mentioned in my comment you can avoid this by making these downloads ajax calls. While you can control the timeout for your browser if this is to be distributed you may not have any control over their browser settings

Comment: @JohnNaegle No rack-timeout nor Heroku in this case. Interesting thought that it might be browser - related. I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Unicorn has a [timeout parameter](https://bogomips.org/unicorn.git/tree/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb#n239)

> sets the timeout of worker processes to +seconds+.  Workers handling
>   the request/app.call/response cycle taking longer than this time
>   period will be forcibly killed (via SIGKILL).  This timeout is
>   enforced by the master process itself and not subject to the
>   scheduling limitations by the worker process.  Due the low-complexity,
>   low-overhead implementation, timeouts of l than 3.0 seconds can be considered inaccurate and unsafe.